# How to make several copies of a directory with `cp`?

Tags: linux, cp

I am running Debian GNU/Linux.

I ran the following commands:

```
mkdir code

cp -Rf code code{1..255}
```

The first cmd created a directory called *code*.
The second command is meant to copy the folder called *code* to *code1*-*code255*'

It is meant to copy the folder code 255 times...
Instead it says:

```
cp: target 'code255' is not a directory...
```

Why does this not work???

```
touch file{1..255} works fine!
```

So why not `cp`?

What is the solution?

=(

Comment: cp does not accept multiple destinations

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the `cp` command is either:

```
cp [options] file copy-of-file
```

Or

```
cp [options] file1 file2... directory-to-copy-files-into
```

That is, it can be a *copy to* or *copy into*.

In the first synopsis above, it can be either. Which it is depends on whether `copy-of-file` already exists and is a directory (or symlink to directory) in which case it's a *copy into* or not in which case it's a *copy to*¹.

The second synopsis is always a *copy into*. If `directory-to-copy-files-into` doesn't exist or is not a directory, you'll get an error.

In your case, your shell expanded that:

```
cp -Rf code code{1..255}
```

To:

```
cp -Rf code code1 code2 ... code255
```

So you're in the second case, *copy into* and you get an error because `code255` doesn't appear to be a directory that `cp` can copy the `code`, `code`, ..., `code254` files into.

In any case `cp` won't make several copies of a file. Here, you'd want to call `cp` for every copy you want to make, for instance by using a loop.

With the `zsh` shell (where that `{1..255}` syntax comes from):

```
for f (code{1..255}) cp -R code $f
```

Or with the `bash` shell (which copied that `{1..255}` operator) and which you're probably using as it's the default user interactive shell on Debian:

```
for f in code{1..255}; do cp -R code "$f"; done
```

Other options include using `xargs`:

```
seq 255 | xargs -I{} cp -R code code{}
```

Or POSIXly (in any modern `sh` implementation):

```
i=1; while [ "$i" -le 255 ]; do cp -R code "code$i"; i=$((i + 1)); done
```

---

<sup>¹, a *copy into* can be enforced portably with `cp file dir/` or with the GNU implementation of `cp` with `cp -t dir file`. A *copy to* can be enforced with GNU `cp` with `cp -T file copy-of-file`</sup>